# “Backup Failed”: Could not restore ‘~/.cache/deja-dup/metadata’: File not found in backup

Tags: nautilus, backup, restore, deja-dup, duplicity

This problem has been reported before and claimed to be fixed. I am getting the same error when backing up which causes my next automatic backup to not start.

**Observations**

- During backup there is a ~/.cache/deja-dup/metadata directory with
  only a README file
- After automatic backup the Deja-Dup application displays, “Backup
  Failed”: Could not restore ‘~/.cache/deja-dup/metadata’: File not
  found in backup"
- After the backup the metadata directory has been removed
- Problem occurs with automatic and manual backups

**Setup**

- Symbolic link from ~/.cache/deja-dup -> /home/backup/data/deja-dup (required because there is not enough space on the disk hosting my home directory)
- Automatic daily backups (occurs at 0200) to large 2 TByte file system (/home/backup)

**Previous Report**

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1217959
- Bug comment from 2019-08-03 says it was fixed, https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1217959/comments/107

**App and Version Details**

apt show duplicity

- Package: duplicity
- Version: 0.8.11.1612-1

apt show deja-dup

- Package: deja-dup
- Version: 40.7-0ubuntu1

uname -a

- Linux  5.4.0-52-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00
  UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Ping - Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hello -- I took this symptom and filed a bug here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup/-/issues/148

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did these follow two steps to fix it:

1 - Remove the installed using apt and install again using snap as suggested here:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup/-/issues/148

2 - Change the path where I save the backup (before: /home/user, now /home/user/bkp)

Hope that help you.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had `.deja-dup-ignore` right into `~/.chache` so

```
rm ~/.cache/.deja-dup-ignore
```

did the job for me.

Comment: Same solution for me (although I had a [`CACHEDIR.TAG`](https://bford.info/cachedir/) file instead of a `.deja-dup-ignore`. `CACHEDIR.TAG` serves the same purpose as `.deja-dup-ignore` (`deja-dup` honores them)

Comment: @MathieuDubois maybe you can upvote then

Answer (score 0):

@MathieuDubois comment put me on the right track.

Looking at deja-dup / duplicity while running using `ps auxf | less` reveals what's giong on.

```
/usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/duplicity  
--include=/home/knagg/.cache/deja-dup/metadata 
--exclude=/home/knagg/snap/*/*/.cache 
--exclude=/home/knagg/.var/app/*/cache 
--exclude=/home/knagg/Dropbox               <- from settings
--exclude=/home/knagg/VMs                   <- from settings
--exclude=/home/knagg/Downloads             <- from settings
--exclude=/home/knagg/.local/share/Trash    <- from settings
--exclude=/home/knagg/.thumbnails 
--exclude=/home/knagg/.steam/root 
--exclude=/home/knagg/.gvfs 
--exclude=/home/knagg/.cache/deja-dup 
--exclude=/home/knagg/.cache 
--exclude=/home/knagg/.local/share/Steam 
--include=/home/knagg                       <- from settings
--exclude=/sys 
--exclude=/run 
--exclude=/proc 
--exclude=/dev 
--exclude=/var/tmp 
--exclude=/tmp 
--exclude=/media/knagg/8BALL/dejadup_backup/gafsa 
--exclude=** 
--exclude-if-present=CACHEDIR.TAG 
--exclude-if-present=.deja-dup-ignore 
--volsize=50 / gio+file:///media/knagg/8BALL/dejadup_backup/gafsa 
--no-encryption 
--verbosity=9 
--timeout=120 
--archive-dir=/home/knagg/.cache/deja-dup 
--tempdir=/tmp 
--log-fd=30
```

Note the parts that are actually from the deja-dup settings.
The rest is obviously built automatically.

So if I understand correctly the `metadata` folder is specifically included first, and that should override the exclusion of `~/.cache` further down.

It would seem that this include/exclude priority system does not quite work with the two `exclude-if-present` lines, and so when something happens to write a `CACHEDIR.TAG` or `.deja-dup-ignore` file to the `~/.cache` dir, this  blocks the `metadata` from being included in the backup, and thus from being restored for verification, triggering this error.

Removing the `CACHEDIR.TAG` file solved the problem for me, without the `~/.cache` dir being included in the backup.

The only problem is if anything else is depending on this file to stay away from the `~/.cache` dir. And also I have no idea how that file was put there, but hopefully, if I don't remember, I will find this post about it :-)